# Java regex match group empty even though it matches

Tags: java, regex

Let's assume I got this line:

`|125148            Schalter f GLE GÜ 90/80Z nei PL 80 16AJ`

And want to match the following two parts:

- **125148**
- **Schalter f GLE GÜ 90/80Z nei PL 80**

16AJ could be used as "break point" so anything from the first letter after the number until the "break point" should be matched in a group.

I got this somehow working with this regex `^\|([0-9])+(.)+(?=\s+16AJ)` but my first group contains 8 characters and my second group contains nothing.

See this [demo](http://regexr.com/3bh36)

What am I missing out here? Why is my second group empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^\|([0-9])+(.+)(?=\s+16AJ)

             ^^
```

You need to take the quantifier inside to capturing group.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^\|([0-9]+)\s+(.+?16AJ)
```

In Java:

```
^\\|([0-9]+)\s+(.+?16AJ)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wM1sW7/1)

This will give you `125148` in first group and `Schalter f GLE GÜ 90/80Z nei PL 80 16AJ` in 2nd group.

Answer (score 1):

The second group isn't empty.  You're capturing `8` in the first group and `0` in the second, which is exactly what I would expect from that regex.  You need to put the quantifiers *inside* the capturing groups.  The way you're doing it, you capture one character at a time, each time overwriting the previously captured character.

I think this is what you're trying for:

```
^\|([0-9]+)\s+(.+?)\s+16AJ
```